# Using iOS static framework giving error in appstore upload

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-frameworks

Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'xx.app/Framework/xx.framework/xx ' is not permitted. Your app couldn't contain standalone library or executables. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide for information on the iOS app bundle structure.

Comment: What's the deployment target?

Comment: @trojanfoe deployment target is 8.1

Comment: OK your question is somewhat confusing.  You say "static framework" and yet something bundled in `xx.app/Framework/xx.framework/xx` would be a **dynamic** framework.  Also if you have set your deployment target to 8.1 then dynamic frameworks are allowed.  You should double-check to make sure that deployment target is being applied to your build *target*.